# How do I find the possible combinations with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

A computer program generates random strings consisting of five letters, which are chosen from any of
the following seven: a, g, j, o, x, y, z, with repetitions allowed.

How many different strings are there that contain two or more identical letters?

I know that the total number of combinations is 7^5 = 16,807. But how do i find out the strings with 2 or more identical letters? Would it just be 16,807 - 7!

Comment: How many strings don't have repeated letters?

Comment: Im not sure, how would i figure that out

Comment: for the first letter you have $7$ choice, for the 2nd $6$ choices, ....can you continue ?

Answer (score 0):

choose a letter to be duplicated: ${7 \choose 1} = 7$

combination of 3 non-duplicate letter: $6\times 5 \times 4 = 120$.

Permute 5 objects, divide by the duplicates: $5!/2 = 60$

Combine these: $7 \times 120 \times 60 = 7! \times 10 = 50400$

Comment: This does not account for the permutations of the string.